# Android Studio only running signing report

Tags: java, android, android-studio

I tried to obtain the SHA-1 value by clicking on the signing report, however, the value wasn't there, it turns out I need to create the key first. Now, my application is only running the signing report - does anyone know how I can make android studio run my application rather than the signing report?

Thanks

Comment: Nevermind, it's been resolved.

Answer (score 0):

You can select what Android Studio should run on the Dropdown Menu in the Menu Bar of Android Studio

[image: Android Studio menu]